# Can I use the length of an embedded entity port?

Tags: vhdl

I would like to use the length of a port of an embedded entity to set the length of a corresponding signal. Is there any simple way without using generics?

Something like this:

```
architecture main_arch of main is
    component timer is
        port ( TIMER_VALUE_O : out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
    end component;

    signal timer_val_s : std_logic_vector(timer.TIMER_VALUE_O'length-1 downto 0);
...
```

Comment: OT: You can use other attributes to better express what you want, for example `left`/`right` or `high`/`low`.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. As far as I know you'd have to use either generics, as you say yourself, or define the length in a package that you use in both modules. There is however the concept of unconstrained data types which might be applicable here - I think. You'd then not constrain the length in the component, but rather in the signal.

Comment: The prefix of the expanded name doesn't denote an entity ([IEEE Std 1076-2008 8.3 Selected names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMGqG.jpg)) nor does it occur within an architecture of that entity.

Comment: Note there is no [mcve] in the question and there is a semantic error in the snippet, wherein the declaration of signal time_val_s occurs within the main_3r_arch architecture statement part instead of as a block declarative item in the architecture declarative part.